# Why are people capturing Carbon dioxide from the air?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am not really sure if this is the correct platform to ask this question. In the recent times, there seems to have more discussion on how to combat global warming and one of the problem is to reduce the emission of green house gases like carbon dioxide. Hence, it is no surprise that one of the solution raise is to remove carbon dioxide from the air. However, I do not understand how does using "Technology" removes carbon dioxide from air. This is because the "Technology" is definitely going to consume electricity to either produce the chemicals required or to convert Carbon dioxide to something else. Since electricity is mainly powered by fossil fuels nowadays, we are still producing carbon dioxide? Please help me to understand this topic. Thanks.

"Technology" is used because some website I was searching does not really state how they change it?

Comment: The idea is to eventually produce less carbon dioxide to do the removal than we are removing, so that the net effect is a reduction. I am not sure whether we have such net-negative technology yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: I second the vote.

Comment: In Iceland, they are making CO$_2$ react with basalt, which creates a different kind of rock. It needs some energy for the pumps, but that comes from hydropower. In principle, this is similar to how CO$_2$ came down from the ancient levels, by weathering of eroding mountains.

Comment: A relevant overview is https://longitudinal.blog/co2-series-part-2-co2-removal/ which does get into the energetic demands of CO2 removal.

Answer (score 3):

Electricity today is not necessarily produced with fossil fuels, but can be from renewable sources as well. The reduced amount of carbon dioxide would lead to less greenhouse effect in the long run. And of course the idea would be to use a method of removal that contributes less carbon dioxide than it removes.